# Some questions about the usage of MethodImpl Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, jit, cil

The MSDN reference of the `MethodImplOptions` are these:

**[MethodImplOptions Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

---

I would like to learn, firstly, in what circunstances I should use `MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Unmanaged)` and the most important thing, what are the beneffits/optimizations of this (if any)?

I suuposed that I should use it when I do a call to WinAPI function or to a function in a third party C/C++ library, then, this code-example is right?:

```
<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Unmanaged)>
Public Shared Sub MyMethod()

    ' Call to
    SafeOrUnsafeNativeMethodsClass.RanodmWinAPIFunction()

End Sub
```

---

Secondlly, I would like to learn what value I should use for methods that are declared as shared in a Class, methods that could be call from any part of the code.

An example:

```
' Sealed class.
Public NotInheritable Class class1

    ' No instanceable class.    
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function MyFunc(ByVal parameter1 As String) As Boolean

        Return A Boolean Value

    End Function

End Class
```

What value of the `MethodImplOptions` EnumerationI should set for that method in the `MethodImpl` attribute?.

Here is an user test that demonstrates inlining causes bad performance:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245802/is-there-a-downside-to-using-aggressiveinlining-on-simple-properties

Howhever, I'm not sure if inlining is what I should specify, of if I should set NoOptimization, or what value that will take best performance in the circunstances of shared methods.

Comment: Where do you see "bad performance" in that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#memberList):

> Unmanaged  The method is implemented in unmanaged code.

This means the method body is in unmanaged code, not that it will get compiled to it. This flag is used in C++/CLI assemblies.

I'd say don't use this attribute, the JIT should handle inlining by itself, when needed (as it is written in the article you posted).